# Android localization from external XML

Tags: android, xml, web-services, localization

Is it possible to translate android application at runtime using XML received from service?
If it is possible could someone please point me in right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd be fairly certain the answer is no. The reason is that the 'automatic' language selection relies on the different localized 'strings' files which are part of the resources. Updating resource files at runtime isn't possible.

Comment: @Squonk Unless I miss understand, that's incorrect. I just did it in my app. There is a screen to choose Spanish or English and allows the user to change which strings file is used based on the selection. Not receiving the XML through a service as it does need to use the strings.xml but it can be changed at runtime

Comment: @codeMagic : I wasn't saying that it isn't possible to change language selection at runtime - that's the point of the localized 'strings' files. The OP (in the title of the question) is asking if it's possible to do it with an "external XML"...that was the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @Squonk ok, sorry, I misinterpreted your last sentence

Comment: @codeMagic : No problem. What I meant by "updating resource files at runtime" was that resources are placed in the `/res` directory and are 'built-in' at compile time. As a result it's not possible to add new resource files at runtime.

Comment: +1 for clarification. I hope we can still be friends :P

Comment: @codeMagic : No offence taken. :)

Comment: What if I set id's of application controls to be same as XML tags in XML file I receive from service. And than use following logic: 

String controleText = getResources().getResourceEntryName(controleName.getId());
controleText.setText(Util.getNameFromXML(test));
XML file would be received when application starts and getNameFromXM(String name) method would search through XML file stored on phone to find matching text and return it.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

Everything I have read says that its not a good idea to let your app change the language because it isn't supported by the Android framework and it may cause problems.

With that being said, I have done it in my app and, while it has been a bit of a pain, it seems to be working so far. Here is how I did it in case you want to do it this way. You need a separate `strings.xml` file for each language. `strings.xml` in `values` folder as your default then maybe a `strings.xml` in say a `values-es` folder for Spanish strings. I have used the following code to change the configuration settings depending on a `RadioButton` that the user selects

```
final Configuration LANG_CONFIG = ChooseLocale.this.getResources().getConfiguration();
Locale newLocale = new Locale("English");
curLang = ChooseLocale.this.getLanguage();
if ((curLang.equals("English")) || (curLang.equalsIgnoreCase("Ingles")))
{
    newLocale = new Locale("en_US");
}
else
{
    newLocale = new Locale("es");
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newLangToast + " " + curLang , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
Locale.setDefault(newLocale);
config.locale = newLocale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = langPref.edit();
editor.putString(LANG_PREF, curLang);
editor.commit();
```

With this line being the most important to update the config

```
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I get the locale from my `getLanguage()` function which can be handled however you want. I also had to add

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    newConfig = Globals.getUserLanguage(this);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

to every activity that allows orientation change  and add this to my `onCreate()` of each

```
final SharedPreferences langPref = getSharedPreferences (LANG_PREF, 0);
if (Globals.langConfig != null)
    this.onConfigurationChanged(Globals.langConfig);
```

I also added `android:configChanges="orientation|locale"` to each activity in the manifest that allows orientation change

[Android Docs on localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)